# What is the Stata-equivalent of this SAS macro?

Tags: stata

I will present the simplified version of what I want to do. I know how to do it easily in SAS but not in Stata.
Let's say I am trying to create a "poor" binary variable = 1 if an observation is classified as poor and 0 otherwise. I want to have two classifications, one is based on real income, and another based on real consumption (these are variables in the dataset).

The SAS macro would be

```
%MACRO poverty_bin(type=, measure=)
DATA dataset;
    SET dataset;
    IF &measure. <= poverty_line  THEN poor&type. = 1 ELSE poor&type. = 0;
RUN;
%MEND

%poverty_bin(type=con, measure=real_consumption);
%poverty_bin(type=inc, measure=real_income);
```

which should create two binary variables `poor_con` and `poor_inc`.

I have no idea how to do this in Stata. I tried doing something like this just to see if nested `foreach` is what I'm looking for:

```
foreach x of newlist con inc {
   foreach y  of newlist real_income real_consumption{
       display "`x' and `y'"
   }
}
```

But it gives an error message saying "variable real_income already defined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you cite implies that earlier code you do not show us created a variable `real_income`.

I do not know SAS but I can tell you that given a numeric variable `x`

```
 gen y = x <= 42
```

will create a variable `y` with value 1 if `x <= 42` and 0 otherwise.

For another such variable, use another similar statement. In Stata and perhaps any other language, setting up a nested loop or defining a program instead of making two statements directly seems overkill. For a number of  new variables much larger than 2, that might not be true.

```
foreach v in x y { 
    gen new`v' = `v' <= 42 
}
```

For completely arbitrary existing names, new names and thresholds it is likely to be easier to write out statements individually.

This is documented. See for example [13.2.2 in [U]](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/u13.pdf) or [this FAQ](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/true-and-false/).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, but I know how to do generate a binary variable like that. I just gave it as an example in order to state my question about how to write a stata macro equivalent to a SAS macro in general.
I know that they both have pretty different data processing procedure.
I am familiar with looping over a variable list and such in Stata, but not familiar with how to incorporate a list of string variable that can be concatenated into the main macro function. I also don't know if there is a way to define a macro function in Stata like in SAS (as I name it "poverty_bin" here).

Comment: As already stated you could write a loop or even a program for this.